# Cant upload image from facebook carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I currently have a user profile that allows users to upload an image file, get crop data using jQuery, then send it to CarrierWave/RMagick for cropping/processing. It's finally working well.

The issue I'm running into now, is if the user signs up with Facebook (oAuth), I want to set their profile image to their Facebook image by default. I want this to be the same field (TalentProfile.profile_image) as I want users to be able to swap it out with a custom upload or remove it if they like.

Here is the flow I have currently:

- User signs up with facebook, User is created.
- TalentProfile resource    is created under the user
- I go to add the profile_image after    TalentProfile creation.

Here is my talent_profile.rb model:

```
class TalentProfile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :profile_image, ProfileImageUploader
    validates :profile_image, file_size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

    def crop_profile_image
        if crop_x.present?
            profile_image.recreate_versions!
        end
    end

    def self.set_facebook_image(profileId, auth)
        @profile = TalentProfile.find(profileId)
        @profile.profile_image = auth.info.image
        byebug
    end
end
```

When self.set_facebook_image is run, it seems that @profile.profile_image can't be set like this, unless I remove the mount_uploader and validates lines. It always comes through as nil, even though auth.info.image is the URL I need. This is leading me to believe that CarrierWave can't handle it like this if I update it; it seems to require a form submission.

How can I go about making this work? Is it possible? Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`remote_profile_image_url`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-remote-image-urls-to-your-seedfile) method to upload images from remote urls.

Comment: Are you saying just change the `@profile.profile_image = auth.info.image` line to `@profile.remote_profile_image_url = auth.info.image`? If so, that doesn't appear to work. Do I have to add that attribute to my model?

Comment: Derp. I changed that line to `@profile.update(remote_profile_image_url: auth.info.image)` and it worked. You're the best! Thank you.